# Regexp to replace key, value in brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, object, string-matching

I've to match/replace a string by the contents of some brackets. So, something like this:

```
var str = '_(foo, bar)'
```

should result in an object like this:

```
var obj = {foo: 'bar'}
```

I tried it with this regexp `/[a-z]+/g`, but no success!

What I need is a function like this:

```
var obj = {};
'_(foo, bar)'.replace(/[a-z]+/g, function (match, key, value) {
    obj[key] = value || key;
});
```

My regex-skills are really restricted and I've no idea how to accomplish this, do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var obj = {};
'_(foo)'.replace(/\(([a-z\d]+),*\s*([a-z\d]+)*\)/g, function (match, key, value){
    obj[key] = value || key;
});    
console.log(obj);
```

**Output**

```
{ foo: 'foo' }
```

You can see explanation to the Regular Expression here http://regex101.com/r/jG1sY6

Comment: Yeah, looks good so far... Problem is that, something like `_(foo)` isn't matched, sadly.

Comment: @yckart What should be the value in that case?

Comment: I expect to get `{ foo: 'foo' }`, as `obj[key] = value || key` assigns ;)

Comment: @yckart Updated my answer. Please check that now.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it, looks much prettier now!

Answer (score 1):

First this regex is wrong:

```
/[a-z|\d]+/g
```

It doesn't do what you think it is doing since it matches a literal pipe character also.

It should be used as:

```
/[a-z\d]+/g
```

OR simply

/\w+/g

You code can be:

```
str = '_(foo)';
obj = {};
str.replace( /([a-z\d]+)(?:\s*,\s*([a-z\d]+))?/, function (m, k, v) { 
      obj[k] = v||k; return m });

console.log(obj); // Object {foo: "foo"}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer! Problem is that something like `_(foo)` isn't matched :'(